# Number of invitations at once

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, invitation-letters

Can I invite two different people at once to the UK, two different friends in the same year?

I invited a friend already and I want to know if it is possible to invite another while the first one is still with me.

Comment: Are you concerned the friends won't get along? Or that you might not have room to house both at the same time?

Comment: How many spare couches do you have?  Or are you expecting them to sleep on the floor?

Comment: I have enough place for them to stay. Just thought I could only invite one person per time/period

Comment: I imagine the issue here is invitations for the purpose of visa applications, not physical space in ones home.

Comment: @Mclittle Are you intending to offer accommodation only, or will you also be providing financial support during the visit(s)? There is nothing in the UK immigration rules or Visit Guidance  https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF preventing you from inviting more than 1 person at one time - it will be common eg in the case of inviting a couple or family members to visit. In the case of friends, you can explain your ‘relationship’ (how long you’ve known each other etc) in a covering letter to the ECO

Answer (score 1):

The [UK Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules#part-v4-eligibility-requirements-for-visitors-standard) have no directive or restriction on frequency of an invitation. What is outlined is the following (added emphasis mine):

> Funds, maintenance and **accommodation** provided by a third party
>
> V 4.3 A visitor’s travel, maintenance and **accommodation** may be provided by a third party where the decision maker is satisfied that they:
>
> (a) have a genuine professional or personal relationship with the visitor; and
>   (b) are not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of decision or the visitor’s entry to the UK; and
>   (c) can and will provide support to the visitor for the intended duration of their stay.
>
> V 4.4 The third party may be asked to give an undertaking in writing to be responsible for the applicant’s maintenance and accommodation. In this case paragraph 35 of Part 1 of these Rules applies also to Visitors. An applicant will normally be refused where, having been requested to do so, the applicant fails to provide a valid written undertaking from a third party to be responsible for their maintenance and accommodation for the period of any visit.
>
> Your **sponsor should also provide a covering letter addressed to the Entry Clearance Officer to explain the background to the invitation, for example why they are inviting you, their relationship to you, confirmation that they will provide maintenance & accommodation and have the capacity to do so.**

In offering to host your friends, you would want to compose an invitation that says:

- you are willing to accommodate them during a specfic time period (dates)
- your status in the UK (e.g., citizen, legal presence)
- the location of the property (address)
- that you have the right or permission to host (e.g., ownership, tenancy agreement, letter from landlord/housing authority)
- your contact information (phone, email)